# Sharing a Google Doc across multiple users' Google Drive using Drive API (v2, Ruby Client, Rails, iOS)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, google-drive-api

Hello Google gurus and Drive API ninjas!

I have a Rails app with the following flow:

a User submits a form
a templated Google Doc is created in the User's Drive
that Doc is shared with another User
that Doc is added to the other User's Drive

Everything is working great up until that last step, causing this humble poster no end of grief. In my mind, my app should be able to call `drive.parents.insert` wherein I pass the `fileId` stored on creation (by User) and the `folder_id` of the Other User's desired folder. Sadly, calls to `drive.parents.insert` (and even  `drive.files.get`) return a status of 404 - file not found. This is a bummer, as the Other User can access the doc at `https://docs.google.com/document/d/#{fileId}` and can manually add the file to their own drive from the Shared With Me tab using the Add to My Drive button provided via the Drive GUI.
So, kind readers, where is my gap in understanding? Must I first call `drive.files.insert` or some other Drive API method? If so
1) Should I be authorizing my request with a fresh auth token belonging to the User or the Other User?
2) If I'm supposed to be using `drive.files.insert`, what is the correct method for declaring the `media` part of the insert for an existing doc? (`media = Google::APIClient::UploadIO...???`)
I'm more than happy to provide extra details on request, though I suspect the problem is conceptual on my end...
Best,
-B

EDIT:

The User who created the Doc can get the file; the Other User who created the folder can get the folder; How do I make these ends meet such that either the User can add his file (shared with Other User) to the Other User's folder or the Other User can add the User's file (on which he is shared) to his folder. Thanks again for your attention.

Comment: Without seeing the code, a guess is that the 404 is referring to the folder. Has "another User" shared the folder with "a User"? PS. it might be worth editing your question to User-A, User-B, etc and be clear which user is seeing the errors.

Comment: Thanks for the reply pinoy! As near as I can tell, the solution to my problem was that the scope 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file' is insufficient for moving a document from the 'Shared With Me' folder to 'My Drive' - once i added 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive' and  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata' to my oAuth scope, things started falling into place. I wish I could provide a helpful link to some documentation, but alas...

Comment: If possible it would be great if you could post an answer as I'm sure it's a not uncommon scenario. Drive.file is the preferred scope so understanding its limitations is always useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question with the solution that worked for me:
As near as I can tell, the scope `googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` is insufficient for moving a document from the 'Shared With Me' folder to 'My Drive'.
That is, I changed my oAuth initializer from:

```
config.omniauth :google_oauth2, '...', '...',
  {
    scope: [
      'email',
      'profile',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
    ],

    access_type: 'offline',
    prompt: 'consent'
  }
```

to:

```
config.omniauth :google_oauth2, '...', '...',
  {
    scope: [
      'email',
      'profile',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
    ],

    access_type: 'offline',
    prompt: 'consent'
  }
```

I found no documentation anywhere suggesting that this was required - quite the contrary, in fact, as the Google documentation recommends `drive.file`. Karmic bonus points to anyone who can direct future readers to any Help Docs where this is mentioned. -B

Comment: Oh, and the Drive API method call was to `drive.parents.insert` as originally expected.